# How to merge two lists into a sequence of columns in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists:

```
t1 = ["abc","def","ghi"]  
t2 = [1,2,3]
```

How can I merge it using python so that output list will be:

```
t =  [("abc",1),("def",2),("ghi",3)]
```

The program that I have tried is:

```
t1 = ["abc","def"]  
t2 = [1,2]         
t = [ ]  
for a in t1:  
        for b in t2:  
                t.append((a,b))  
print t
```

Output is:

```
[('abc', 1), ('abc', 2), ('def', 1), ('def', 2)]
```

I don't want repeated entries.

Comment: `[...]` is a list, `(...)` is a tuple.

Comment: Sorry Christian and thanks for correction

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Python 2.x, you can just use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> t1 = ["abc","def","ghi"]
>>> t2 = [1,2,3]
>>> zip(t1, t2)
[('abc', 1), ('def', 2), ('ghi', 3)]
>>>
```

However, in Python 3.x, `zip` returns a zip object (which is an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#iterator)) instead of a list.  This means that you will have to explicitly convert the results into a list by putting them in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
>>> t1 = ["abc","def","ghi"]
>>> t2 = [1,2,3]
>>> zip(t1, t2)
<zip object at 0x020C7DF0>
>>> list(zip(t1, t2))
[('abc', 1), ('def', 2), ('ghi', 3)]
>>>
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think you read it right the first time.  I think the zipped list is what the OP wants, what you've written is what the OP's attempt produced, but the OP "[doesn't] want repeated entries".

Comment: @DSM - That's it.  I need another coffee...

Answer (score 6):

Use zip:

```
>>> t1 = ["abc","def","ghi"]
>>> t2 = [1,2,3]
>>> list(zip(t1,t2))
[('abc', 1), ('def', 2), ('ghi', 3)]
# Python 2 you do not need 'list' around 'zip'
```

If you do not want repeated items, and you do not care about order, use a set:

```
>>> l1 = ["abc","def","ghi","abc","def","ghi"]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> set(zip(l1,l2))
set([('def', 2), ('abc', 1), ('ghi', 3)])
```

If you want to uniquify in order:

```
>>> seen=set()
>>> [(x, y) for x,y in zip(l1,l2) if x not in seen and (seen.add(x) or True)]
[('abc', 1), ('def', 2), ('ghi', 3)]
```